# Unable to append string to a string builder object

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am new to Java and hoping someone may have experienced this behavior. I've created a `StringBuilder` and I am trying to append a String to it. I get the following error:

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I've tried importing `java.lang.*;` package and it still errors out at line `sb.append(" To Java");`

Could any one point me in right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
package CoreJava;

public class StrngBuildrClas {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Welcome";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("s1");
    sb.append(" To Java");
    System.out.println(sb);
  }

}
```

Comment: If `java.lang.CharSequence` can't be resolved, you have a basically broken installation. What's your environment - how are you trying to compile this, which version of Java are you using etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String ab="To Java";
                 sb.append(ab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should compile for JVM8. Make sure you [download java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and use it in your IDE ([best set it in PATH](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml))

And the code is *almost* ok. It should probably look like that:

```
public class StringBuilderClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // you can put the string here, but I think it's less clear then
    String s1 = "Welcome";
    sb.append(s1);
    sb.append(" To Java");
    System.out.println(sb);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I just happen to update my Java files. Currently on version JRe1.8.6 from jre1.8.51.

I am still getting the below error after following above suggestions

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

 at CoreJava.StringBuilderClass.main(StringBuilderClass.java:27)

Comment: are you sure you are using the proper JVM? How do you compile your program?  Type `java -version` in your cmd window and/or configure your workspace's build path to use jvm8.

Comment: By Configuring workspace which is using JVM 8

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\client\jvm.dll